# Quickly Closed Rhino Question

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, closed-questions

I have a question which I'd really like input from the Rhino community on:

[Rhino - dead in the water?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012293/rhino-dead-in-the-water)

It got closed about almost as quick as I asked it, and I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Was it my last "less and less relevant" question that was "argumentative"?

Or should I just ask the question again? Maybe removing that line and changing the title?

All moderator advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did you want to know about Rhino? You went off on a tangent it seems.

Comment: I'd like to know how to improve the question to get an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd have voted to close the question after reading it all the way through, but seeing the title certainly would have set me firmly down that path. "Rhino - dead in the water" just *screams* "subjective and argumentative". I'm sure you're trying to be clever in picking a title, but you have to be careful, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a question that's less about writing code, and more about the status of the project itself. That sounds to me like a question that would be a better fit at [Programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) than Stack Overflow — please consider asking it there!

Comment: Thank's for the quick response - and exactly the answer I was looking for; I get it now. Off to Programmers.se I go.